# ReactJS Why is my DOM / `display` only rendering 'display: none'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Driving me a bit nuts here...
I want to click a `Preview` button and it generates a Preview Pane for text input. I thought i'll get the div's inline-style linked to React state.

```
<div className="preview-container" style={{ display: this.state.showPreview ? 'visible' : 'none' }}>
    {
        this.state.showPreview && 
          <Preview
            htmlString={value.toString('html')}
            showOrHidePreview={this.togglePreview}
          />
    }

</div>
```

But even though i can see state changing when i click the button,
*AND* i've successfully changed a border colour by linking it to state - for some reason changing display to none just sticks. it wont move off it.

Any ideas?

Updated (fairly standard toggle handler):-

```
 togglePreview = () => {

    if (this.state.showPreview === false) {
      this.setState({
        showPreview: true,
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        showPreview: false,
      })
    }

  }
```

Thanks v.much @AdrianoRepetti for the suggestion of `display: block` rather than `visible`. Not sure where i picked up `display: visible` from.

If anyone else happens across this, i also found a hack using opacity: 10 vs opacity 0. Though that was scraping the barrel a bit.

Comment: please add the code of where you are setting the `showPreview` flag

Comment: Share event handler function of preview code as well

Comment: @NewbieAid maybe because `display: visible` is NOT valid (try, for example, `display: block`) then the change goes simply ignored.

Comment: Using `display: none` is useless because when `this.state.showPreview` is `false`, the `<Preview />` pane is removed from the DOM completely, so the `<div className="preview-container">`is empty anyway.

Comment: thanks @AdrianoRepetti - see above edit. 

Comment: Lukas is right – this is an antipattern. If you want to *hide* the element (to reserve its dimensions on the page) use `visibility: visible` and `visibility: hidden`. Also note that opacity goes from 1 to 0, not 10 to 0.

Comment: You welcome. Just a small note: hidden (`display: none`) elements are not rendered in the visual DOM while `opacity: 0` and `visibility: hidden` are and they contribute to the overall layout. Mind the difference because _sometimes_ you might want to use `display` and some other times you may want to use `visibility`. Also note that, from a performance point of view, you may want to avoid frequent insertions/deletions from the DOM (then `this.state.showPreview && ` thing might be omitted)

Comment: Unrelated to the original question, but you can replace your long `togglePreview` function with something a lot simpler: `this.setState(prevState => ({showPreview: !prevState.showPreview}));`

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this code:

#### 1.

`display: visible` is incorrect and will have no effect (ignored by browser). The correct value here is `display: block`.

#### 2.

You are removing the contents when `showPreview` is `false`, so `display: none` has no effect either.

#### 3.

When showPreview is `false` you are asking React to render the value `false`. This is wrong, and you will get error.

#### 4.

The max value of `opacity` is `1`.

#### 5. (potentially)

What is the initial value of showPreview? If `undefined`, your toggle will set showPreview to `false`, giving you the impression that it didn't do anything at all.